# Existence of Differential Operator for Fundamental solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function, fundamental-solution

Suppose we are given a function $G(x,y)$. Under what conditions on $G$(continuity, smoothness, singularity?) does there exist a linear differential operator $L$ such that $LG(x,y) = \delta(x-y)$ ?

I'm guessing that $G$ has to have a singularity somewhere.

I know this question is quite broad, so any intuition here is appreciated.

Comment: A more tractable place to start might be looking for operators such that $LG=0$. It may also be useful to look at Fourier representations of $L$ and approaching it from that end